# Using Subqueries in the Where Clause

Tags: mysql, logic, subquery

I submitted a similar problem.
Display customer id and name for all customers who have at least one purchase in the first of the three months and at least one order in either second or in the third.

NOt sure if this is correct:

```
set @rundate = current_date;
set @Mnth_1 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
set @Mnth_2 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
set @Mnth_3 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
Select c_id, c_name
From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_1, '%M %Y')
and order_id in (
     Select order_id
     From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
     Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_2, '%M %Y')
     or Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_3, '%M %Y'))\G
```

Comment: Is it giving some error there?

Comment: No error. Need to check results to see if this is correct. Just wanted a second opinion.